# Use custom data for bar chart data labels in echarts4r

Tags: r, echarts4r

I have a stacked bar chart and I want to add a value label above each stacked bar. I don't want values for each section of the stack.

This yields a value for each section of the stack:

```r
library(echarts4r)

set.seed(1)

d <- data.frame(
  xaxis = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 2)),
  groups  = c("c", "d", "c", "d"),
  value = rnorm(4, mean = 50)
)

d |>
  group_by(groups) |>
  e_chart(xaxis) |>
  e_bar(value, stack = "grp1") |>
  e_labels()
```

[image]

I just want one number above each bar, equal to the sum of each section.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can precalculate the labels of your groups and then bind them to e_bar :

```
library(echarts4r)
set.seed(1)

d <- data.frame(
   xaxis = c(rep("a", 2), rep("b", 2)),
   groups  = c("c", "d", "c", "d"),
   value = rnorm(4, mean = 50)
   ) |>
   group_by(xaxis) |>
   dplyr::mutate(Label = ifelse(groups == "c","",as.character(sum(value))))

d |>
  group_by(groups) |>
  e_chart(xaxis) |>
  e_bar(value, stack = "groups",
     bind = Label,
     label = list(
       show = TRUE,
       formatter = "{b}",
       position = "outside"
     )
  )
```

Comment: Thank you! Does the `b` in `formatter = "{b}"` stand for "bind" and thus references the bound data?

Comment: not exactly, "bind" adds a name argument to the data and with {b} you can reference it. other options are also available :  https://echarts.apache.org/en/option.html#series-bar.label.formatter