# How I can show the labels on echarts4r plot but just every 2 or 3 bars?

Tags: r, echarts, echarts4r

Hi and thanks for reading me. Im working on a echarts plot in R and I want to show the label of the vars but only in every 2 or 3 bars, because i don't want it to look too saturated with information

I haven't found a working argument to e_labels(), could someone help me?

My code is the following:

```
library(echarts4r)

mtcars |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> 
  e_charts(model) |> 
  e_bar(cyl) |> 
  e_legend(F) |> 
  e_labels()
```

Comment: You cross posted this question. Another solution was mentioned here https://github.com/JohnCoene/echarts4r/issues/516#issuecomment-1510244601. please close the issue on GitHub. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a good way to do it with `mtcars` is to create a label column which contains text when the value in `cyl` is different to the previous row. We can then bind the label to the bar as set out in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73966219/use-custom-data-for-bar-chart-data-labels-in-echarts4r) answer.

```r
mtcars |>
    tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |>
    dplyr::mutate(
        cyl_changed = cyl != dplyr::lag(cyl, default = TRUE),
        label = ifelse(cyl_changed, cyl, "")
    ) |>
    e_charts(model) |>
    e_bar(
        cyl,
        bind = label,
        label = list(
            show = TRUE,
            formatter = "{b}",
            position = "outside"
        )
    ) |>
    e_legend(F)
```

[image]

If your real data doesn't have this property you can create a label every three rows, e.g:

```r
    dplyr::mutate(
        label = ifelse(
            dplyr::row_number() %% 3 == 0,
            as.character(cyl),
            ""
        )
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

Another approach would be not using formatter but doing it like this with the help of `e_add_nested()`:

```
library(echarts4r)
library(dplyr)

df <- mtcars |> 
  tibble::rownames_to_column("model") |> arrange(model)
df$show <- rep(c(TRUE, FALSE, FALSE), 
               length.out = nrow(df))

df |> 
  e_charts(model) |> 
  e_bar(cyl, label = list(position = "insideTop")) |> 
  e_add_nested("label", show) |>
  e_legend(F)
```